# Mass adding people to a whitelist

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

I have a big list of names I want to add. Since Mc 1.8.1 added json whitelist I can't just paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you need to do it manualy

if you not lucky to maybe some day find a whitelist adding program but for now you need to do it manualy

Comment: Anyway that we can set up a program to get the UUID and generate the json file?